# Azure devops skip build pipline

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

Good morning Guys,
I'm looking for a solution what would make a revert on a git repository. Basically I had on realized pipeline task when it fails it will trigger another one what schedule a revert using a git revert command but that rever trigger a build pipeline what not exactly thing what I want, do you have some idea how to solve this query.

for git I using command

```
git reset --hard <last good commit>
git push --force origin <release branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can think of
- if possible change the git commit message of the previous commit to contain `***NO_CI***`
- have a task in your revert pipeline to disable CI on your build via API, reset git, then enable CI via API again

I would go with the second option if it was me

Comment: Could you gide me to how to disable CI on your build via API ?

Comment: @Michal You can write a script to call the REST API to update the build definition : [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: You can press F12 in the browser  to capture the request body.Then you can edit the definition in the body.You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865945/can-i-mass-update-vsts-build-pipeline-definitions)